# Flutter go_router package is not displaying all pages

Tags: flutter, router

I created a Flutter app using go_router based on this article: https://blog.devgenius.io/guide-to-go-router-flutter-1ddcfa56d39c
I simply added another route '/login', but this page is not being displayed, while the setup is completely identical.
The routes are defined in *routes.dart* like this:

```
static final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(path: rootRoute(), builder: _homePageRouteBuilder),
      GoRoute(path: homeRoute(), builder: _homePageRouteBuilder),
      GoRoute(path: loginRoute(), builder: _loginPage),
      GoRoute(path: detailBlogRoute(), builder: _detailBlogWithParams),
    ],
    errorBuilder: _errorWidget,
  );

static loginRoute() => '/login';

static Widget _loginPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      LoginPage(key: state.pageKey);
```

And this route is called in a similar way like the other routes in *loggedin_signup.widget.dart* like:

```
  onPressed: () => context.push(AppRouter.loginRoute()),
```

**Note**
using **context.go** instead of **context.push** does not help.

Also note that in the console log this line is displayed:

```
  [GoRouter] pushing to /login
```

The full example can be found here:
**https://github.com/robinbakkerus/go_router_issue.git**

Answer (score 0):

While debugging, I was able to figure out this issue myself. It is rather tricky and I can image others will stumble against the same problem.

The problem was that GoRouter handled this path: **/login** as if **login** was a path parameter! Hence it ended up navigating to the root path **/**

How could this happen, well the GoRoute routes were defined like :

```
class AppRouter {
  static const rootRoute = '/';
  static const loginRoute = '/login';
  static homeRoute([CurrentTab? type]) => '/${type?.name ?? ':type'}';
  static detailBlogRoute([String? id]) => '/article/${id ?? ':id'}';

  static Widget _homePageRouteBuilder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      HomePage(
          key: state.pageKey,
          currentTab: state.pathParameters.isEmpty || state.pathParameters['type']! == CurrentTab.blogs.name
              ? CurrentTab.blogs
              : CurrentTab.favorites);

  static Widget _detailBlogWithParams(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      SingleArticleWithParams(id: state.pathParameters["id"]!, key: state.pageKey);

  static Widget _loginPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      LoginPage(key: state.pageKey, dummy: true);

  static final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(path: rootRoute, builder: _homePageRouteBuilder),
      GoRoute(path: homeRoute(), builder: _homePageRouteBuilder),
      GoRoute(path: loginRoute, builder: _loginPage),
      GoRoute(path: detailBlogRoute(), builder: _detailBlogWithParams),
    ],
  );

  static GoRouter get router => _router;
```

Hence the **homeRoute** method has an optional parameter, an Enum indicating if the /blogs or /favorites path should be used.

After starting this app the debug console shows:

```
[GoRouter] Full paths for routes:
             => /
             => /:type
             => /login
             => /article/:id
```

so we have a path: /:type and /login
And with this setup context.go('/login') or context.push('/login') threats **login** as a path parameter.

An easy fix is to make the login path more explicit by renaming like for example:

```
static const loginRoute = '/do/login';
```

or alternatively make the homePage route more explicit

```
static homeRoute([CurrentTab? type]) => '/blogs/${type?.name ?? ':type'}';
```